# How to upvote or flag a comment on a touch device?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I use a touch device to browse SE. So when I see a comment I want to make more visible I upvote it.

But when I'm using a touch device (Windows 8 tablet) since you don't hover over the comment is impossible to make comment options available.

Someone figure it out?

Comment: Related on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174657/touch-friendly-comments

Comment: Actually Microsoft solved this. In the new version of IE available in Windows 8.1 is possible to do all those "hover" actions. Just long press where you usually hover your mouse and it will hold the comment in the "hover" mode. Is far from perfect but solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can tap a comment and that will bring up a options to up-vote, flag, edit and delete. Well at least it does on my Android devices.

Comment: Your "Android device" you meant a tablet or a phone (perhaps an hybrid too)?

Comment: I tested with my tablet, but from memory it does the same on my phone.

Comment: It open the full version? Because even in Windows Phone 8 I can't do this. I think it is because open the full version.

Comment: Ahhh I am using the mobile version. But now I get your problem and I guess it makes sense to want to use the full version on your tablet. But, I would imagine there are a lot of other problems with pressing small buttons and notifications on a touch screen, so the mobile version is still a good option even though your tablet is running a "proper" OS.

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken. On my tablet I am viewing the full site and can tap on a comment to get the available actions. On my phone I am viewing the mobile site and I can already see the available actions.

Comment: If I tap the comment I actually select some text.